# Is asking for others' "experience" a good enough reason to flag a post for closure as "opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

I was left speechless by getting my [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126826/batch-start-method-cpu-timeout) flagged for closure as "opinion based" (I can easily imagine by who). Just because I've asked if there are people experiencing the same problem to share their experience (and maybe solution!). I wonder if I have to learn better something about what content can go in a SFSE question or there has been a bit of over-patrolling in this case. Thank you :)

Comment: super late/for the record: questions getting closed is rarely a definite outcome. Often it's to stimulate you to edit the question and ask for it to be reopened. We  probably can express that more explicit in comments.

Comment: @MLucci, while you can "guess" who flagged your question, be aware that it takes 5 votes to close a question. Not all who vote will necessarily vote to close it for the same reason as it may have been originally flagged for closure and not all will vote for to close, some may vote for it to remain open. Ultimately, it still takes 5 votes to close a question, regardless of the reason they're cast.

Comment: for the record: it was justified my question being flagged/voted for closure as it was initially missing details, what brought me question here in META is that it seemed to me the "opinion-based" reason was being applied *because I was asking other's experience* (which is also kind of a redundant ask to put in a SFSE post). I might have got the wrong impression though. BTW all is well what ends well (except my issue is still outstanding...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `Opinion Based` was a little surprising, but I do agree that it should be closed for a different reason: `Too Broad`. If you cannot share your query or any other code with us, there are a great number of reasons you might be having trouble, all of which are somewhat speculative. I guess that speculative nature is what led to using the `Opinion Based` flag.

It's not a question that really lends itself well to our format here. In general, if you cannot show a concrete, reproducible example of what is going wrong, your question is difficult to apply to a general audience.

If you can show your `WHERE` clause with pseudo-fields, I at least will concede that a concrete answer can be provided. Something like:

```
WHERE TextField__c = 'Some Value'
AND Parent__c IN :someCollection
AND Datefield__c > TODAY
```

Comment: Point taken on the fact I should make an effort on giving my question more context/data. I'll do that if the question doesn't get killed before.

Comment: @MLucci They are also easy to reopen. :)

Answer (score 7):

If you can translate "*are you experiencing the same ?*" to "*Can you reproduce this bug/flaw?*" it is probably fine but you want to pay attention to wording it so people know what kind of answer you're expecting.

If questions are more along the lines of "*What is your experience with solving this very broad business demand?*" it is too broad and opinion prone and the question will get closed.

I hope that provides some insight. After your edits some of us voted to reopen the question  :-).